# how to take printout setting from my php page?

Tags: php, html, css

i want to take printout of report but i used in my code

```
style="overflow:auto;height:600px;"
```

so while pressing print option it showing only 600px records rather than showing full report.
Please give some suggestion so i can take printout of all records.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can create a seperate Print stylesheet, so that these styles will be applied when someone prints the page - http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/05/how-to-create-a-simple-print-css-for-your-site/

Comment: Or change height:600px per height:100% ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have two CSS files, one for showing content on screen and another for printing.

```
<link ...href="screen.css" media="screen" />
<link ...href="print.css" media="print" />
```

You may specify different styles in `screen.css` and `print.css` for the same style elements.

e.g.
**style.css**

```
.some-element {
    height: 600px;
}
```

**print.css**

```
.some-element {
    height: auto;
}
```

> Please consider this as a starting point and not as a copy-paste code.

Comment: +1 cause thats the way to do :) and most sites forgets to produce a print style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a stylesheet, not a style attribute
2. Use [an `@media` rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) to specify different styles for print media